# How can i make computer read a python file instead of py?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, installation

I have a problem with installing numpy with python 3.6 and i have windows 10 64 bit 
Python 3.6.6 
But when i typed python on cmd this appears 
Python is not recognized as an internal or external command 
I typed py it solves problem but how can i install numpy 
I tried to type commant set path =c:/python36 
And copy paste the actual path on cmd but it isnt work 
I tried also to edit the enviromnent path through type a ; and c:/python 36 and restart but it isnt help this 
I used pip install nupy and download pip but it isnt work

Comment: you use `pip install numpy` (if pip is added to your environment path)

Comment: How can i add pip to my invironment path

Comment: check this link https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/

Comment: I follow the all instructions step by step tge final step said that type pip in cmd i typed but it said pip is nog recognized i also type pythin and daid python is not recognized

Comment: Are you sure you put the right path where python3.exe is installed when you added it to the path? did you try restarting your computer ?

Comment: Yes i already restart after i added c:/python3.6/scripts

Comment: This means that i add thsi  is path to computer yo understand it

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install numpy`. To install python 3 packages you should use pip3

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the `py` command should be able to launch any Python version you have installed. Each Python installation has its own `pip`. To be sure you get the right one, use `py -3.6 -m pip` instead of just `pip`.

---

You can use `where pip` and `where pip3` to see which Python's pip they mean. Windows just finds the first one on your path.

---

If you activate a virtualenv, then you you should get the right one for the virtualenv while the virtualenv is active.

Comment: Why this works instead of pip? I understand the python is not in the environment path and i add c:/python36/scripts   is it related to why ise py -3.6 -m pip instead of pip

Comment: Why i dont type python-3.6 -m pip